# Embedded images not showing

Tags: xamarin.forms

This is my page in portable project

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Corcav.Behaviors;assembly=Corcav.Behaviors"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyMobileApp;assembly=MyMobileApp"
                 x:Class="MyMobileApp.MainPage"
                 x:Name="MainPage">

      <Image Source="{local:ImageResource myimage.jpg}" />
```

This is my ImageResourceExtension in same portable project

```
namespace MyMobileApp
{
    [ContentProperty("Source")]
    public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
                return null;

            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source);

            return imageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to add  myimage.jpg as embedded in root of my project and in  Resources folder, but no image is shown.

While debugging I see that the returned imageSource is of type Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource. How do I check if this is really found?

Can anyone spot the error here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct XAML was to add the app name to the source.

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource MyMobileApp.myimage.jpg}" />
```

Answer (score 10):

By default the image will have Build Action: None; this needs to be set to Build Action: EmbeddedResource.
Right click on Image > properties > set [Build Action: EmbeddedResource]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9RXS.png)

Comment: Even after using the app name I was not able to load the image. Setting the Build Action was what I had to do to get it to work. Thanks Osama!

Comment: I have done this, but nothing works.
How do I link the image to his file that I have set as an embedded resource?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the intent of the extension a bit more? Assuming you are putting your images in the proper folders ('Resources' on iOS, 'Resources/Drawable' on Android), then all you need in your XAML is just:

```
<Image Source="FeaturedAreaMockup.jpg" />
```

That will find the images in the appropriate folder and show them - why aren't you just doing that? What's the point of the extension?

Comment: Images are inside the shared project together with xaml files and viewmodels. I don't want to put same images on each project.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Just be sure you are doing this for specific uses. There are many times you will want to put them in each platform project so that you factor in support for retina images on iOS, and supporting different size images (in drawable-hdmi, drawable-xxhdmi, etc.) for varying screen densities (and memory abilities) on Android.

Answer (score 0):

To read assets/resources folder you need to use:

```
ImageSource.FromFile("myimage.jpg");'
```

`ImageSource.FromResource` uses images included as `EmbeddedResource`

More here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated I the image is embedded

Comment: You also mentioned Resources folder, which is used for images that are retrieved with `ImageSource.FromFile`. I though it would be useful. Now, I see that you use separate project for resources.