# Syncfusion Xamarin Listview not displaying any items

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, data-binding, syncfusion

I want to insert a syncfusion linearlayout listview, but for some reason it's not displaying any items/data, and I'm not getting any errors at the same time, I tried changing binding syntax and a couple things, but I cannot seem to get it right.

This is my xaml:

```
            <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="listView"
                ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={local2:BandInfoRepository}, Path=BandInfo, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemSize="100"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
                <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" Padding="0,12,8,0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid RowSpacing="0" Padding="8,0,8,10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=BandImage}"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    HeightRequest="80"
                                    WidthRequest="70"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                />
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                                    Padding="5,-5,0,0"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=BandName}" 
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        FontSize="16"
                                        BackgroundColor="Green"
                                        TextColor="#000000" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Path=BandDescription}"
                                        Opacity="0.54"
                                        BackgroundColor="Olive"
                                        TextColor="#000000"
                                        FontSize="13" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="1" 
                                HeightRequest="1"
                                Opacity="0.75"
                                BackgroundColor="#CECECE" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            </syncfusion:SfListView>
```

And this is the class where I'm getting the data from:

```
public class BandInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string bandName;
    private string bandDesc;
    private ImageSource _bandImage;
    public string BandName
    {
        get { return bandName; }
        set
        {
            bandName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BandName");
        }
    }

    public string BandDescription
    {
        get { return bandDesc; }
        set
        {
            bandDesc = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BandDescription");
        }
    }

    public ImageSource BandImage
    {
        get { return _bandImage; }
        set
        {
            _bandImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BandImage");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

And just in case, this is how I'm filling the collection (BandInfoRepository.cs):

```
public class BandInfoRepository
{
    private ObservableCollection<BandInfo> bandInfo;

    public ObservableCollection<BandInfo> BandInfo
    {
        get { return bandInfo; }
        set { this.bandInfo = value; }
    }

    public BandInfoRepository()
    {
        GenerateBookInfo();
    }

    internal void GenerateBookInfo()
    {
        string[] BandNames = new string[] {
            "Nirvana",
            "Metallica",
            "Frank Sinatra"
        };

        string[] BandDescriptions = new string[] {
            "Description",
            "Description",
            "Description"
        };

        bandInfo = new ObservableCollection<BandInfo>();

        for (int i = 0; i < BandNames.Count(); i++)
        {
            var band = new BandInfo()
            {
                BandName = BandNames[i],
                BandDescription = BandDescriptions[i],
                BandImage = ImageSource.FromResource("Lim.Images.Image" + i + ".png")
            };
            bandInfo.Add(band);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me out as I've been stuck with this for a while now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is ItemTemplate bound to a repo?

Comment: @Jason It's a class, I just took the example and renamed classes for more "appropiate" names for my project.

Comment: I'll add the whole .cs so you can see it.

Comment: look at Ivan's answer below, he is pointing out the same problem I am

Comment: Already tried it, I changed the "ItemTemplate" to "ItemSource" and part of the data is showing now, but I can't still get the BandImage to work

Comment: I think you just want to bind that to a string with a path or url in it

Comment: Currently trying, will update with result, thanks for your help

Comment: Already did, but I got the same result, the images are not being shown. I changed every ImageSource and replaced it with a string, also removed everything from the "for" cycle and left this: BandImage = "Lim.Images.Image" + i + ".png"

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343966/binding-image-source-dynamically-on-xamarin-forms

Comment: every image is already included on every project, I added them to both Images folder and Resources folder (currently working on iOS) but nothing shows up.

Comment: Update: I just fixed the problem with the images, I went back to ImageSource and set up the build action to embedded resource. Took from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952074/embedded-images-not-showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you unintentionally bind `ItemTemplate` twice and not bind any 
`ItemsSource` even once.

Comment: Let me check that, I'm new to OOP and Xamarin too, will try to fix it

Comment: Seems like it's partially working now, but the BandImage binding is still not working and some other properties as well, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

We have looked into your code snippet and we have found that you have binded the underlying collection to  ItemTemplate property instead of ItemsSource property. Further to bind the underlying collection you have to set your ViewModel(i.e. BandInfoRepository) as BindingContext for ContentPage. Please refer the below code snippets to know how to set BindingContext for your page and also to bind the underlying collection into the ItemsSource property.

Code Example:[XAML]

```
<ContentPage>
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:BandInfoRepository/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <ContentPage.Content>
    <listView:SfListView x:Name="listView" ItemSize="70" ItemsSource="{Binding BandInfo}" >

      <listView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <Grid x:Name="grid" RowSpacing="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid RowSpacing="1">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Image Source="{Binding BandImage}"
     VerticalOptions="Center"
     HorizontalOptions="Center"
     HeightRequest="50" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                  <Grid Grid.Column="1"
    RowSpacing="1"
    Padding="10,0,0,0"
    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="{Binding ContactName}"/>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="1"/>
              </Grid>
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </listView:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
    </listView:SfListView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

For your assistance, we have attached the working sample link below.

Sample link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/186932/ze/ListViewSample905947849